# Compile time issue in String query in UI Path

Tags: uipath

I'm struggling with a string query. I got that compile time error:

```
insert into FundTransactions(FundName,RequestType,RequestFrom,RequestStatus,Quantity)
  values("+"'"+strFundName+"'"+","+
         "'"+strFundTransactionType+"'"+","
         "'"+strFromEmail+"'"+","
         +'"Received"'+"'"+strFundQuantity+"'"+");
```

Comment: This is not UiPath. Could you explain what you are tryining to do? Also improve your Tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create SQL insert query using VB.Net Variables as values.
Following should work when assigned to a string variables.

```
    "insert Into FundTransactions(FundName,RequestType,RequestFrom,RequestStatus,Quantity)
  values('"+
  strFundName                  +"' , '"  +
  strFundTransactionType  +"' , '"+
  strFromEmail                   +"' ,'Received','"+
 strFundQuantity+
 "');"
```